# Finding Isomorphic images and proving things are not isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

so I just need a gentle push to help get me started here! I've been combing over the details in my book and I really just can't find a way to show two things are not isomorphic. Let $\mathbb{Z}$ be the integers and $\mathbb{Q}$ be the rationals. I think it should have something to do with identities... but i'm just not sure! Any tips are appreciated.

a) Show $3\mathbb{Z} \ncong 2\mathbb{Z}$

b) Show $\mathbb{Z}[x] \ncong \mathbb{Q}[x]$

c) Find all homomorphic images of $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: As groups, $2\Bbb Z$ and $3\Bbb Z$ are definitely isomorphic. However, you've used the tag [tag:group-isomorphism]. If you're talking about rings, you ought to say so.

Comment: The tag `group-homomorphism` doesn't apply. Please edit your question and tags to clarify what you're asking.

Comment: To elaborate on what @Arthur said, it is possible for sets to be isomorphic as one structure (groups in this case), but not as another (rings). So, it is important to specify what sort of homomorphism you’re talking about (between groups, or rings, or some other structure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have wrongly tagged the question and the structure on these mathematical objects is of ring.

part $(a)$, they are isomorphic as groups as both are infinite cyclic group and upto isomorphism every infinite cyclic group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Assuming there is a typo, Suppose there is an isomorphism of rings $2\mathbb{Z}$ and $3\mathbb{Z}$ then it would give an isomorphism of the underlying abelian groups and you can show that there are only two such maps. Check whether they satisfy the ring homomorphism properties.

Hint for part $(b)$, Unit of $\mathbb{Z}$ are .... and units of $\mathbb{Q}$ are .....

Hint for part $(c)$ To find all homomorphic image of $Z$ you need to find all the ideals of $Z$ and find all quotient ring.